# Providing Google login in Metro app, avoiding repeated permission-grants (Oauth2/Google OpenID)

Tags: microsoft-metro, openid, google-openid, google-oauth

I have the following situation:

I'm currently attempting to write a Metro-style application, with the ability to let the user sign in with his Google account, and the app requestion several permissions, as Userinfo.profile and Userinfo.email.

For this I'm currently using OAuthv2, and requesting the details worked out fine (after quite some effort and research).

***Url used :***

```
const string url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?" +
                   "client_id=" + clientId +
                   "&redirect_uri=" + "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" +
                   "&response_type=code" +
                   "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" +
                   "&access_type=offline";
```

Now the problem is, if I want the user to stay authenticated, I'd either have to do it by saving the token at the clientside, by the user, or find some way to log in using Google, keep the session and check if he is authenticated.

Problem is, I don't know how to perform the latter, and have no idea how to use it.
At the moment, every time I open the application, the user is redirected to the google authorization page, where the whole procedure starts over and over again at each restart.

What I want to accomplish is that if a user logs in, I have some way of identifying him, and not always put a burden on him by re-requesting permissions for the given details.

I looked into [OpenID](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID?hl=nl), but I always get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrds:XRDS xmlns:xrds="xri://$xrds" xmlns="xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)">
<XRD>
<Service priority="0">
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server</Type>
<Type>http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0</Type>
<URI>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud</URI>
</Service>
</XRD>
</xrds:XRDS>
```

As a response on this url :

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.return_to=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&openid.ns.ui=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0&openid.ns.ax=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.required=email,firstname,language,lastname,country&openid.ns.ext=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0&openid.ext2.consumer=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.return_to=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&openid.ext2.scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

Am I building it wrong ?

If any suggestions, on either how to perform this 'correctly', what I'm trying to accomplish (an integration with google, allowing the user log in using google email, and ***only*** if he **hasn't** authorized the application, ask him to do so, plus finding a way of who he is when logging in for a second+ time), or on how I could do it, please feel free.

Besides, by using the stripped down version of the .Net 4.5 framework, it seems I'm unable to use OpenID libraries as they rely on the full 4.5 .

****Edit**** Looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856915.aspx) this comes up :

```
To support SSO, the online provider must allow you to register a redirect URI in the form ms-app://appSID, where appSID is the SID for your app.
```

Does this mean it just isn't possible? Because at google I can only request a key for a domain with `http(s)://` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this? https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

It looks like you are using the Webserver flow and are requesting offline access. This should give you a refresh token after you swap the code. Hold onto this token in your application. If you do an authorization for login as well, you'll get a token back and you can use that to get the userid of the user at Google

Your application should keep track if you have a valid refresh token for a particular user. Then use that token to get the current credentials. You can use tokeninfo enpoint to validate the token. If you have a valid token for the user, there is no need to send them through the code flow to get another refresh token.

If you use the tokeninfo endpoint, the userid field is only present if the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile scope was present in the request for the access token. The value of this field is an immutable identifier for the logged-in user. Store this and you should have a durable identifier of the user.

Comment: Yes I have, and indeed I recieve the an authorization token, trade it for an access token etc. That works fine, but what if the user logs out of the application, to what Google url should I redirect them to receive their appropriate identifier, so I can figure out which token to use? Something like a page where the user logs in, and I receive his userId, so I know which token to use? All [of this authorization](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) works fine.

Comment: For installed applications, we currently don't have a way for you to send the user to us and not have them prompted. This is possible for js client apps but we prevent it for installed apps for security reasons. The user logging out of your app should be very rare, like maybe if they wanted to switch accts. You could leave them logged in permanently and just let them add accts and switch.

Comment: I see, and as a side question (perhaps update your answer with this, and the security reasons part), where should the clientSecret and Id be stored ? Because if an application is disassembled, they might just be looking at the secret, so what should I do in this case? Or doesn't that really matter?

Comment: Installed apps have no true secrets for the reason you state. Your best hope if someone one steals your client id and uses up your quota is to change client ids. If your installed app is on android, you should be using the Google Play Services and not the installed app flow.

Comment: Ok, good to know .. So it'd be better to store that somewhere else and retrieve it elsewhere, perhaps using some sort of webservice probably.